# Show that any finitely generated subgroup of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that any finitely generated subgroup of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$

I have tried :

Suppose $H = \langle \frac{a_1}{b_1},\frac{a_2}{b_2},\dots,\frac{a_n}{b_n} \rangle$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are coprime and integer for all $i$.

We know that any finitely generated subgroup of $(\mathbb Q,+$) is cyclic.

So $H =\langle \frac{a}{b}\rangle$, so $H$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Could anyone check my solution?

Thank You

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The main point is that you can rewrite all the generators to have a common denominator.

Comment: Looks good.  Copy (or paraphrase) your solution into an answer, and mark the question as answered.  (I'll even upvote it.)